# How to disable a checkbox inside a table in eclipse SWT

Tags: eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have created a table as below.

```
Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.CHECK | SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL);
```

Would like to disable check box of a particular TableItem. I have tried setChecked(false) and removeListener(SWT.CHECK, myListener). But still the table is allowing to select the check box. Is there any way to disable that particular tableItem.

Comment: There isn't any way to do this in the basic table code. You would have to draw the table yourself using the MeasureItem, EraseItem, PaintItem listeners.